# "Value Cannot Be Null" when using LINQ to SQL to Group By and Sum results from a WCF Service request

Tags: c#, wcf, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use LINQ to SQL to sum a row in a a resultset returned from a WCF service. I'm able to use LINQ for basic selects, for order by, for filtering, etc.  So far so good.

But when I try to Group By / Sum, I get an error message "Value Cannot Be Null" when trying to Take(5) from the query below.  (`results` is non-null and has 1000+s of items, but the `query` is null when we try to return it:)

**EDIT:** I've removed the invalid cast as mentioned in the answer below, instead selecting the aggregate results into a custom class written to order.  Now the page runs without error -- but the group by / sum doesn't work.... I just get the top five highest values in the results, not summed by group.    Why?

```
var query = (from h in results
            group h by h.Order into hh                     
            select new TopOrders()
            {
                Order = hh.Key,
                Total= hh.Sum(r => r.Price)
            }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Total);

return query.Take(5).ToList();
```

Only possible wrinkle I can point to is that Order is itself a collection (OrderID, OrderName, etc.) and so I've tried grouping explicitly on hh.Key.Order.OrderID and so forth, to no effect.

Anything I'm missing from what you can see?   Thanks.

Comment: Try `group h by h.Order into hh`

Comment: Tried that, thanks, and edited the question to reflect it.  Same error, though.  The select new seems to bring back nothing no matter which group by syntax I try (I've tried a bunch of variants...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably that `r.Price` of a few orders is null, so use `Sum(r => r.Price ?? 0)`. But it's a bit of a guess without knowing your data.

**Edit**
It's so obvious that I overlooked it: you try to cast an IEnumerable of an anonymous type to `List<TopOrders>`, which is not possible. But the `as` operator produces `null` if the cast is not valid. So `query` itself is `null`! Either remove the cast, or create `TopOrder`s in stead of anonymous types.

Comment: I'll try that.  I scanned the data and didn't *think* there were any nulls, but this seems like a good check either way.

Comment: Thanks.  So I've changed the anonymous type to List<TopOrder> query = ...   which I assume would be a valid cast.   And it still produced the same error.  I think it's still considering 'query' to be a List of an anonymous type, despite the fact that I eradicated 'var'.  What might I be missing?  Sorry, I'm still getting my head around this stuff.

Comment: Some progress - now group/sum is not returning valid results though.  Thanks again.